# Wrapping VB Application project with COM project

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to establish the feasibility of using our company's product with COM.  To do this, I've written a (MyAppCom) dll within the solution and referenced the original (MyApp)exe project.  MyAppCom creates and instance of the MyApp (mainform).

The main problem I am coming up against is that the application entry point is an application type (with settings, startup forms, etc.).  Generally, this isn't so bad, but there are a couple issues that I'm banging my head against.

1. The app config uses the calling exes name to search for the application configuration file (i.e. if I'm calling a com instance of MyApp via Python, its looking for python.exe.config instead of MyApp.exe.config.  I've sidestepped this issue for the moment by just copying the settings file, but if anybody knows how to reference this specific config settings, any help would be appreciated.
2. The second point is a bit more sticky.  It seems that MyApp has set mainform as its startup form, which seems to create a global instance of it.  I've looked everywhere and there's no explicit initializations of mainform except through MyAppCom.  This becomes a problem when I initialize mainform from MyAppCom and child forms are trying to reference the global MyApp.mainform.  In this case, it is obviously not initialized (since I didn't create it from MyApp).

Is this something other people have done?  I've searched for a couple days now with no luck but I don't imagine I'm one of few who've tried.  A little background on the product - it was originally written in VB6 and now is updated to VB.NET with new projects in C#.  The wrapper is also written in C#.

Here is the com wrapper (MyAppCom) (names have been changed to protect the not-so-innocent):

```
    public interface  IMainCom
    {
        void Init();
    }

    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    public class MainCom : IMainCom
    {
        private MDIMain mMDIMain = null;


        public void Init()
        {
            OpenMain();
        }

        private void OpenMain()
        {
            mMDIMain = new MDIMain();
            mMDIMain.Show();
        }
    }
```

Here also is the App.Designer for MyApp:

```
Namespace My

    Partial Friend Class MyApplication

        <Global.System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()>  _
        Public Sub New()
            MyBase.New(Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.AuthenticationMode.Windows)
            Me.IsSingleInstance = false
            Me.EnableVisualStyles = false
            Me.SaveMySettingsOnExit = true
            Me.ShutDownStyle = Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.ShutdownMode.AfterMainFormCloses
        End Sub

        <Global.System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()>  _
        Protected Overrides Sub OnCreateMainForm()
            Me.MainForm = Global.MyApp.MDIMain
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Comment: Pretty important to understand the difference between an out-of-process server, an EXE like your VB6 project created.  And in in-process server, a DLL like your VB.NET project created.  Everything you are asking about is related to that difference.  They are not equivalent at all, .NET has very poor support for out-of-process servers.  You'll need to decide if this is *really* the way you want to progress.  Probably not.

Comment: Yeah, that's really what I'm trying to figure out.  The product would really benefit from being COM accessible, but there are significant architecture differences in the way it was designed in VB6 and the direction we are trying to take it.  So my big overarching question here, is there a way to work around these issues or would it require a redesign of the way that the application form is referenced internally.